# 42 Spaces Open on Mission Control on starup (mavericks)

Tags: macos, mission-control

On startup, when I press f3, I have 42 spaces open in mission control. Is this normal? Is there anyway to limit the amount of spaces that are open on startup in OSX? I don't remember this happening for versions before Mavericks.

If it helps i'm on a 2011 15 inch macbook pro (early).

Comment: No.  That it not normal.  When you say "Space" are you referring to a desktop space?  Like Desktop 1 - 42?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am talking about. Thank you. It seems that mavericks just wants to use all of my ram?

Comment: Have you tried closing them all, and restarting to see if they're still there?

Comment: weird, before I had done that, and they reappeared. I just did that now and they are all gone! I wonder if it has anything to do with me reattaching my thunderbolt display? Does it create a new desktop space every time I do that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it might.  I'm going to submit an answer to this question with what I said, mark it as correct to help other people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a bit tedious, but try closing all of the spaces and then restart your machine.  OS X will keep the spaces you had open when you restart, so if you restart with none it should start with none.